# There is no unique constraint, even though I'm referencing primary keys?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

Lets say I have:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
   a int, 
   b int, 
   PRIMARY KEY(a, b)
);
```

This works successfully. Now I have `a` and `b` as the primary keys (which implies that they are unique).

Then I do:

```
CREATE TABLE B (a int, 
   b int, 
   FOREIGN KEY(a) REFERENCES A(a), 
   FOREIGN KEY(b) REFERENCES A(b)
);
```

But this gives me an error `there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "a"`

Comment: That's not how foreign key constraints work.  Where you have a composite primary key you need to reference the entire key from your foreign key constraint.

Comment: It's a shame this is a duplicate because this question is a better question than the duplicate. It has less going on and is more of a `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`.

Answer (score 1):

You've said the combination of `a` and `b` make a unique key, but that doesn't imply that both `a` and `b` are unique, for example:

```
a | b
-----
1 | 2
1 | 3
2 | 2
```

would be valid in your table `A`, but then which row would the following row reference in `B`?

```
a | b
-----
1 | 2
```

`a` could reference 1,2 or 1,3 and `b` could reference 1,2 or 2,2

That is what the error is complaining about.